# Integrate Calabash in jenkins android

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, calabash-android

I have developed a test using calabash-android. Everything runs how it should. Now I want to run the scenarios in Jenkins.

1) Which plugin should I install in Jenkins?

2) How run I a test? Currently I am using the command: calabash-android run  , I did not achieve another way.

3) What I have to install additionally in the server?

Answer (score 8):

- Install [`Android Emulator plugin`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin). You need a virtual device to run your tests.
- Install `Rake` and `RVM` plugins as described [here](http://moduscreate.com/integrating-bdd-cucumber-test-suites-jenkins-3-steps/). You need `ruby` installed in `jenkins` in order to run your tests using `calabash-android` gem.
- Create `shell script` in `jenkins` and install [`Bundler`](http://bundler.io).
- Add `gemfile` to your workspace and specify required gems. In our case we need `calabash-android` gem:

  ```
  # A sample Gemfile
  source "https://rubygems.org"

  # gem "rails"
  gem "calabash-android", "0.5.12"
  ```
- Run `bundle install` in `jenkins` using shell script. It will install `calabash-android` gem.
- Run your tests from folder which contains `gemfile` from **4th** step. At this moment you should have `bundler` and `calabash-android` installed in `jenkins`.

  `bundle exec calabash-android run "PATH_TO_APK" ADB_DEVICE_ARG=${ANDROID_AVD_DEVICE}`

  `${ANDROID_AVD_DEVICE}` - emulator name, provided by `Android Emulator plugin`.
- You might need also [`Cucumber reports plugin`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Reports+Plugin) and [`Cucumber test results plugin`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Test+Result+Plugin).

**Update:** Screenshots from `Jenkins` job and shell script.

- Android emulator config for the **1st** step

[image: Emulator config]

- Ruby environment for the **2nd** step

[image: Ruby environment]

- Shell script for the **6th** step

[image: Shell script]

- Cucumber test reports for the **7th** step

[image: Cucumber test reports]

- Cucumber + calabash project structure. `calabash` folder is in the root folder of the `Android` project.

[image: Files structure]

- `Cucumber.yml` file contains different cucumber related settings. Especially there are specified features for the platform. And it's possible to select platform using parameter `"-p android"` or `"-p ios"`.

[image: cucumber.yml]

- `.calabash_settings` contains information about `keystore` used for the `.apk` signing during the build. `Calabash` needs the same `keystore` for the `test_server` signing.

[image: .calabash_settings]

**run_android_features** script:

```
cd ..

PARAMS="-p android"

while getopts ":rd:" OPTION; do
        case $OPTION in

                r)
                    PARAMS=$PARAMS" --format json -o cucumber.json"
                    ;;
                d)
                    PARAMS=$PARAMS" ADB_DEVICE_ARG=$OPTARG"

                    ;;
                [?])    echo "Usage: $0 [-r] [-d DEVICE_ID].\n     -r: should create reports.\n     DEVICE_ID: where to run tests."
                        exit 1;;
        esac
done

# clear old files
rm -rf screenshot*
rm -rf test_servers
# resign apk
bundle exec calabash-android build "../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk"
# run tests
bundle exec calabash-android run "../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk" $PARAMS
```

Comment: Hi Veaceslav. Do you have a sample project setup on github to show all the steps? Thanks alot

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have sample projects published.